# c++ quick find in structure

Tags: c++, find

I have a little problem . I have to write a function and i dont know how.
I tried everything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct sBase
{
    string NAME;
    string AGE;

};

list <sBase> FIND_NAME(list <sBase> &MYLIST_ONE, const string Name, bool PART)
{
    list <sBase> NEW;
    list <sBase>::iterator SOLUTION = find(MYLIST_ONE.begin(), MYLIST_ONE.end(), Name); // FULL OF ERRORS . I NEED HELP HERE
    NEW.push_back(*SOLUION);

    return NEW;
}

int main()
{
    list <sBase> MYLIST_ONE;//List including people. I used another function that add people to this.

    string Name
    cout << "Type a name : ";
    getline(cin, Name);

    string ASK;
    bool PART;
    string yes = "YES", no = "NO";

    cout << "Is name only a part of a text ?(YES OR NO) :";
    getline(cin, ASK);

    if (ASK = yes)
        PART = true;
    if (ASK = no)
        PART = false;

    list <sBase> MYLIST_ONE = FIND_NAME(list <sBase> &MYLIST, const string Name, bool PART) //FUCTON SHOULD RETURN A NEW LIST INCLUDING ONLY STRUCTURE OF THIS ONE PEARSON


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

IF PART IS TRUE IT MEANS THAT IT IS JUST A FRAGMENT OF TEXT .FOR EXAMPLE I PUT John ,PART TRUE SO RESULT CAN BE Johnaka alaka,or John Flower.

```
IF PART IS FALSE IT HAS TO BE FULL NAME : john new,PART false ... result - john new and other iformations.
```

I would be grateful if you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refactoring a little, removing (most of) the capitalised variable names leaves this:

```
struct sBase
{
    string name;
    string age;

};

struct has_name_like
{
    has_name_like(const std::string& name)
    : _name(name)
    {}

    bool operator()(const sBase& sbase) const
    {
        return (sbase.name == _name);
    }

private:
    std::string _name;
};

list <sBase> find_name(const list <sBase>& input_list, const string Name, bool PART)
{
    list <sBase> result;
    list <sBase>::const_iterator iter = find_if(input_list.begin(),
                                                input_list.end(),
                                                has_name_like(Name));
    if(iter != input_list.end()) {
        result.push_back(*iter);
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    list <sBase> mylist_one;//List including people. I used another function that add people to this.

    string Name;
    cout << "Type a name : ";
    getline(cin, Name);

    string ASK;
    bool PART = false;
    static const string yes = "YES", no = "NO";

    cout << "Is name only a part of a text ?(YES OR NO) :";
    getline(cin, ASK);

    if (ASK == yes)
        PART = true;
    if (ASK == no)
        PART = false;

    list <sBase> mylist_two = find_name(mylist_one, Name, PART);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

which will at least compile. You may want to re-think the logic of what you're trying to achieve. did you really want to extract a list containing 0 or 1 copies of the sBase, or did you just want to find it if it exists (in which case just use the result of `find_if` as demonstrated).